# Optional relationship in SQL Server -- How to implement in SSMS Schema Designer

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-schema, relationships, table-relationships

I have two cases where I would like to set 'optional' relationship inside one table or between two tables.

First:

[image]

I want to set this relation as optional, in other words: there will be categories and subcategories in one table, so subcategory column is only optional.

Second:

[image]

Here I want to make sure that House cannot exist without Member (mandatory relation), but Member can be without any House (optional relation).

I don't have any experience with Microsoft SQL Server and I don't have idea how can I modify these relations.

Here is the end result in Oracle diagram:

[image]

Comment: Just make the optional FK columns NULLable, and the mandatory ones NOT NULLable.

Comment: @TabAlleman I think he's already got that -- from those Oracle diagrams, I think the red star indicates that the field is NOT NULL, hence lack of a star would be NULLable.

Comment: I don't know Oracle, but if he's already got that, then what is left to be missing?

Comment: @Gregy - I gather that you've used the SQL Server designer to create this schema, and you're asking how to use it to set the optional Foreign Key relationships as NOT NULL in the designer?

Comment: To create diagrams I have used Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. The last one is from my database in Oracle environment. I think that you are right with setting FK as NOT NULL, I was just confused because of visual relationship line presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how this can be done in the schema designer (DB Diagram) in SQL Management Studio, it's easy:-

1. Right-click the table in the digram, choose 'Table View' -> 'Standard'

[image: Right-clicking the table]

2. In the 'Allow Nulls' column, set the optional Foreign Keys to 'Allow Nulls'

[image: Setting NULLable in designer]

3. Press Ctl + S to save the updates to the schema.

Additional details about the selected object in the designer (column, table, FK etc.) are available by viewing the Properties window (usually in the right of the screen). For example, here are the properties for the `subcat` column in the example:

[image: subcat properties]

Comment: You are 100% right, I have made it exactly same way, but I though that I missed something because of relationship visualisation.

Comment: It's a little strange that just the column names appear in the default view when creating a DB diagram (at least that's my experience). It would be easier if the Standard view was shown.

Comment: Thank you a lot for support :)